# Getting Substring after certain char in python

Tags: python, kaggle

I want to cut a String such as "0011165.jpg_Fish" to get only Fish, so everything after the "_", how do i do that in python?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `"0011165.jpg_Fish".split("_")[1]`?

Comment: Yeah, it does work, Thank you!

Comment: how do i use this on a whole dataframe? like 
train['Label'] = train.Image_Label.split("_")[1] ?

Comment: `train['Label'] = train.Image_Labels.str.split("_").str[1] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `str.partition` instead of `str.split`. This is robust, since you can always expect `3` items, unlike, split which maybe tricky to handle if the `input string` doesn't have the `split character`,

```
>>> word = '0011165.jpg_Fish'
>>> not_required, split_char, required = word.partition('_')
>>> required
'Fish'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"0011165.jpg_Fish".split("_")[1]
```

And in case of a Dataframe

```
train['Label'] = train.Image_Labels.str.split("_").str[1]
```